# What's this howling noise when starting after a cold night?

Tags: noise, kia

My Kia Picanto '2004 with 1.1 engine (I'd mention in the Hyundai Getz, which has the same motor), makes [this howling noise](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IPNeNrX0PesjoXdfVNVdfVrCYKItjIgM/view?usp=sharing) when starting the motor after a cold night. 
The volume of the noise decreases within a few seconds, but it stays noticeable for maybe a minute.

In the past, it made this noise only when it's very cold, like -8°C, but now this happens every morning, though the temperatures are around 0°C.

Any idea what could be the cause of this noise?
It's not the belts, since those would sound different, plus I poured some water of them to exclude they make the noise.

Comment: Are you revving up the engine by pressing the accelerator or does it rev up by itself? Anyway, doesn't sound like belts to me, I agree.

Comment: It sounds like the power steering pump.